# using prop value in useState hook gives undefined value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

Have a React Component that sets a state using hooks from props.
prop is storedStep.
prop value is used to setState in a hook.

But state is set to undefined, even if console.log says prop has a number value

```
line 41     console.log(storedStep)
      const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(1);
      const [activeStep2, setActiveStep2] = React.useState(storedStep);
line 44      console.log(activeStep)
line 45       console.log(activeStep2)
```

[image]

This is for a material ui stepper
https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

I am setting the active step of a Stepper
https://codesandbox.io/s/qhhv1?file=/demo.js
The example in the demo for the stepper does not use a prop to set the active Step, but sets it to 0.

***Where storedStep is defined.***

It's defined in the direct parent component.

I use another hook in direct parent

```
const [projDetail, setProjDetail] = useState({});
```

and pass the setProjDetail function in the useEffect of this parent

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await getDetailFunc (email, projectid, setProjDetail);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [email, projectid,getDetailFunc]);
```

getDetailFunc will fetch the detail and set the projDetail using setProjDetail

storedState is a property of projDetail which is passed to the child

```
storedStep={projDetail.requeststatus}
```

storedStep is correctly getting the value 0 at some point(line 41). But not able to set it to the activeStep(line 45)

Comment: Show where `storedStep` is defined?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and a set of steps to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in my case by rendering the child component  in parent only after checking for existence of the attribute "requeststatus"

```
if (projDetail.hasOwnProperty("requeststatus")) {

.....
...
    <Stepper
      steps={steps}
      storedStep={projDetail.requeststatus}
      saveStageFunc={saveStageinDynamo}
      updateKey={{ email, projectid }}
      labelArray={processStates}
    />

}
```

Comment: Take a look in the react docs on [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), something like `projDetail.requeststatus && <Stepper ...`